# Unable to pretty print Json to text file

Tags: java, json

I need to Pretty print a JSON object in a text file as you can see, but what I'm able to do now is only Pretty print the JSON object as output. If I try to print it out to a text file it won't be pretty print but rather a single default JSON line.

Can you please take a look at this??

```
package com.crunchify.tutorials;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class CrunchifyJSONFileWrite {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("Name", "crunchify.com" );
        obj.put("Author", "App Shah");

        JSONArray company = new JSONArray();
        company.add("Compnay: eBay");
        company.add("Compnay: Paypal");
        company.add("Compnay: Google");
        obj.put("Company List", company);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement je = jp.parse(obj.toJSONString());
        String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);

        System.out.println(prettyJsonString);

        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:/Users/12056/Desktop/pluginnetbeans/jasontestfile.txt")) {
            file.write(prettyJsonString);
            System.out.println("Successfully Copied JSON Object to File...");
            System.out.println("\nJSON Object: " + obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Its probably how you are viewing the file. Open it in something like GEdit or Notepad++.

Comment: Yes it works, you have to open it with other viewer. Thanks alot!